# pyspark 'SparkSession' object has no attribute '_jssc'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm using:
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.14.2
SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101

And I'm getting this error when starting the directStream from KafkaUtils:

```
  File "/home/ale/amazon_fuse_ds/bin/hdp_amazon_fuse_aggreagation.py", line 91, in setupContexts
kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream( self.spark_streaming_context, [ self.kafka_topicin ], kafka_configuration )
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 145, in createDirectStream
 AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute '_jssc'
```

and I see that SparkSession has _jsc method but _jssc. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you pass is a `SparkSession`, why you should pass `StreamingContext`.

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

ssc = StreaminContext(self.spark_streaming_context.sparkContext, batchDuration)
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ...)
```